# C# Grammar & GrammarBuilder '' rule reference not defined in this grammar

Tags: c#, voice-recognition, speech

I'm trying to reuse some words, but when I try to reuse a list of Choices, I get this error. Except when I don't.
"'' rule reference not defined in this grammar."

In two programs I have:

```
List<string> words = new List<string>();
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("wordsEnTest.txt"))
{
    if (line.Length > 0)
    {
        words.Add(line);
    }
    else { }
}
Choices omniChoices = new Choices(words.ToArray());
GrammarBuilder omniBuild = new GrammarBuilder(omniChoices);
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
   omniBuild.Append(omniChoices, 0, 1);
}
Grammar grammar = new Grammar(omniBuild);
engine.LoadGrammar(grammar);
```

and this works fine if **i** goes to **100**, but not to **3**. Which is very strange to me.
I've had similar problems with patterns like "noun conjunction noun" as well.
I'm not sure what I'm overlooking.

e.g.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
   omniBuild.Append(omniChoices, 0, 1);
}
```

works, but not

```
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
   omniBuild.Append(omniChoices, 0, 1);
}
```

The threshold seems to be four of the optional (0,1) choices. Above that, it doesn't seem to crash. Alternately, making the first set of choices 0,1 also seems to avoid the error.

The exception:

```
System.FormatException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message='' rule reference not defined in this grammar.
  Source=System.Speech
  StackTrace:
       at System.Speech.Internal.SrgsCompiler.GrammarElement.System.Speech.Internal.SrgsParser.IElement.PostParse(IElement parent)
       at System.Speech.Recognition.GrammarBuilder.InternalGrammarBuilder.CreateElement(IElementFactory elementFactory, IElement parent, IRule rule, IdentifierCollection ruleIds)
       at System.Speech.Recognition.GrammarBuilder.CreateGrammar(IElementFactory elementFactory)
       at System.Speech.Recognition.GrammarBuilder.Compile(Stream stream)
       at System.Speech.Recognition.Grammar.LoadCfg(Boolean isImportedGrammar, Boolean stgInit)
       at System.Speech.Recognition.Grammar.LoadAndCompileCfgData(Boolean isImportedGrammar, Boolean stgInit)
       at System.Speech.Recognition.Grammar.InitialGrammarLoad(String ruleName, Object[] parameters, Boolean isImportedGrammar)
       at System.Speech.Recognition.Grammar..ctor(GrammarBuilder builder)
       at VAI.Program.LoadWords() in C:\Users\Corbin\Desktop\VAI\VAI\Program.cs:line 71
       at VAI.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Corbin\Desktop\VAI\VAI\Program.cs:line 34
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: I know nothing about what you're working on, but I suggest you re-tag your question with "speech recognition" instead of "grammar". (The grammar tag refers to a different kind of grammar.) I also note that your "for" statement starts i at 1 instead of 0, which is the typical way to write for statements in C# - but maybe that's what you want?

Comment: I tried to, but apparently I need to "unlock" those tags by posting more (edit: nvm, found voice-recognition). The 1 or 0 is arbitrary in this case. I counted the first addition so I started at 1.

Comment: OK, sorry I can't help more, I have no experience in this area, just C# in general. But just to be 100% sure - your "for" statement will only execute twice, for i = 1 and i = 2.

Comment: What is exactly the exception text you get? What are the contents of you wordsEnTest.txt? You can share it to provide more information. Don't paste it because it might loose some bytes. Overall this issue might be caused by incorrect input to API. For example you pass whitespace-only string to choices.

Comment: wordsEnTest.txt:
a
aah
aahed
aahing
aahs
aardvark
aardvarks
aardwolf
ab
abaci
aback
abacus
etc